# Applications of shortest path problem

Tags: biological-networks

The shortest path problem is the problem of finding the shortest path between multiple nodes. What are the applications of the shortest path problem in biology?

A simple google search gives me this - http://mutage.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/2/191.full.pdf
This, unfortunately is under a paywall.

Apart from that article, I can't find anything else useful.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There are several applications. This question is too broad. (Not my downvote btw)

Comment: @WYSIWYG like? A simple google search doesnt give me anything...

Comment: look for "bioinformatics" instead of "biology". ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic application is analysis of graph data. For example, [protein-protein interaction networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein%E2%80%93protein_interaction) or [gene regulatory networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_regulatory_network) and the like. There are various types of data that can be presented in the form of a network and network analysis is an integral part of Systems Biology.

Another example is determining the similarity of functional annotations from the [Gene Ontology](http://geneontology.com). One of the ways of doing so is finding the shortest path between two nodes in the GO graph.

Or, for a more concrete example, I recently published a paper where I examined various features of a particular group of proteins. One of the pieces of information I used was how central these proteins were to the network and, for this, I measured how often they served as a node in the shortest path between two others.

The simplest way for you to find more example is to go to PubMed and search for "shortest path":

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=shortest+path

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Can you please give me a link to your paper?

Comment: @TanMath [here you go](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2015/150609/ncomms8412/abs/ncomms8412.html), but it won't help you much. The shortest path analysis was a tiny part of the work, I only mentioned it because I happened to have done this recently. Your best bet is to go on PubMed and [search for "shortest path"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=shortest+path).

Comment: Hace you seen my latest question about influenza? Do you know anything about that?